# Switch play store account without accepting ToS?

Tags: google-play-store

I accidentally swapped accounts(to Account2) on the play store and now I cannot switch back to the original account(Account1) without accepting the ToS for Account2. Is there any way to switch back to Account1 or is Google forcing me to accept the play store ToS for Account2 in order to get back to Account1?

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you either accept the ToS, or remove the account, you're unable to access the Play Store's interface therefore not allowing you to switch accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Having recently run into the same issue, I found another solution:

Assuming "Account1" is the first Google account on the device, you should also be able to switch back to it by uninstalling updates to the Play Store app.

Updates can be uninstalled using the Settings app by navigating to Apps > Google Play Store, tapping the overflow menu, and selecting Uninstall updates.

At this point you'll be running an older version of the store, but it should take care of updating itself in the background.  If it seems to be taking a while, you may be able to hasten the update by opening the Play Store's in-app Settings menu and tapping on Build version at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found was to go into application manager and clear data. Reverted back to original account.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be:

> Force stop the application
>   Clear the data
>   Clear the cache

It worked for me and hope will for you.